# NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY stores the wrong date

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

I've been using `NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY` to store a date and time to datetime attribute, but it stores date 1 day and 17 hours upfront, not 2 days upfront as it should.

Do anyone knows why is that?

Comment: Is NOW() by itself giving the datetime that you expect?

Comment: Can you show exactly how are you using it? can you show you query? also can you please show the output of this query 
`show variables like 'time_zone'`

Comment: Do an select now()  to check your server time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NOW()` function returns a `DATETIME` value in the current connection's time zone setting.

It seems likely that you expect a value of `NOW()` in the `America/New_York` time zone, also known as EST.  It seems likely you're getting a value in the `UTC` time zone.

Try using this query to set the time zone.

```
SET time_zone='America/New_York'
```

then retry your use of `NOW()`.